# SalesForce RestAPI or SOQL

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, soql

How to retrive the SecuritySettings of the organization in Salesforce. There is a metaDataAPI available, but it uses soap for retriving. I need to retrive the SecuritySettings using Oauth 2.0 RestAPI or SOQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_api_tooling.htm).

`SecuritySettings` doesn't show up on the list in documentation but `GET /services/data/v54.0/tooling/sobjects/SecuritySettings/describe` looks very promising. And from there you can query it or deploy/retrieve or whatever you want, it's similar to Metadata API.

```
/services/data/v54.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT Id, DurableId, Metadata, FullName, IsAuditFieldsInactiveOwnerEnabled, NetworkAccessId, IsRequireHttpsConnectionEnabled, SingleSignOnSettingsId, CanUsersGrantLoginAccess, IsAuraSecureEvalPrefEnabled, IsAdminLoginAsAnyUserEnabled, PasswordPoliciesId, SessionSettingsId FROM SecuritySettings
```